# Origin Triangle Tetrahedron Volume

Tags: geometry

I have a problem that goes like this:

Triangle $ ABC$, with sides of length $ 5$, $ 6$, and $ 7$, has one vertex on the positive $ x$-axis, one on the positive $ y$-axis, and one on the positive $ z$-axis. Let $ O$ be the origin. What is the volume of tetrahedron $ OABC$?

I really can't wrap my head around this problem. I thought I could find the area of the triangle base by using Heron's Formula, and then multiply that by $1/3$ of the height, but I've got no way of finding the height.

The posted solution for this question was very confusing.

It says:

wlog use $A(a,0,0), B(0,b,0), C(0,0,c)$

(i) wlog set $ 5 = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \qquad 6 = \sqrt{b^2+c^2} \qquad 7 = \sqrt{c^2+a^2}$

(ii) Square for $ 25 = a^2+b^2 \qquad 36 = b^2+c^2 \qquad 49 = c^2+a^2$

(iii) Adding and dividing by 2 gives $ a^2+b^2+c^2 = 55$

(iv) Subtracting each element of (ii) from (iii) gives $ a^2 = 19 \qquad b^2 = 6 \qquad c^2 = 30$

(v) Multiplying gives $ a^2b^2c^2 = 19 \cdot 6 \cdot 30 = 19 \cdot 5 \cdot 6^2$

(vi) Squareroot and divide by 6 to get $ V = \frac{1}{6} abc = \sqrt{95} \implies \boxed{\text{C}}$

What I don't understand about this solution is why they are using these $a, b$, and $c$ coordinates and taking the square roots of two coordinates added together and setting them equal to the triangle's side lengths.

Perhaps I just don't properly understand how tetrahedrons and $x$-$y$-$z$ coordinates work. I'd really appreciate some help wrapping my head around this problem.
Thanks :)

Comment: See [Distance Formula](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/distance_formula/index.php).

Comment: If you copied this solution from a post on MSE, please give due credit to the original post

Comment: This is 2008 AMC12A problem 18 http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2008_AMC_12A_Problems/Problem_18

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will help you to visualize

[image]

$OA^2 + OB^2 = 5^2\\ 
OB^2 + OC^2 = 6^2\\
OA^2 + OC^2 = 7^2$

And even though it looks quadratic, it is really a system of linear equations.

If it feels strange to treat variables with squared terms as linear equations, rewrite it as:

$x + y = 25\\ 
y + z = 36\\
x + z = 49$

And once you have $x, y, z$ finding the volume is $\frac 16 \sqrt {xyz}$

Answer (score 1):

Because $A$ is on the $x$-axis, there exists a number $a$ such that the coordinates of $A$ are $(a,0,0)$.  Similarly, there exist numbers $b$ and $c$ such that the coordinates of $B$ and $C$ are $(0,b,0)$ and $(0,0,c)$, respectively.

We know that $AB,BC,$ and $CA$ are $5,6,7$ in some order.  We may assume $AB=5,BC=6,$ and $CA=7$, because otherwise we could relabel the tetrahedron so that this is the case.

Note that $\triangle OAB$ is a right triangle, so $OA^2+OB^2=AB^2$.  But $OA=a,OB=b,$ and $AB=5$, so the equation becomes $a^2+b^2=25$.

Is the rest of the solution now clear?

Comment: Oh shoot I just noticed that my rep is exactly 1234 right now

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand about this solution is why they are using these a, b, and c coordinates and taking the square roots of two coordinates added together and setting them equal to the triangle's side lengths.

**HINT:** You've been given the side lengths, so in the solution they are solving for the coordinates of the three points. If your question is, *why* this method works for solving those coordinates, then have a look at this simple diagram of a tetrahedron:

[image]

It has three points on each $x$,$y$ and $z$ axes respectively. Can you identify three right triangles in it, coplanar with the $xy$, $yz$ and $xz$ planes? Now, can you apply the Pythagoras theorem...?